# Make the number of columns dynamic

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I work with django and django-tables2, and I have a question:
How I can render the number of columns dynamic?  Each column represents a year.

I aggregate some number over years, but I don't now how many years are relevant for this subset.

Sometimes there are two years so I want to get a table with 3 columns:
Data, 2011, 2012. But sometimes there are four years so I want to have a table with five columns: Data, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012. I want to say that the number of columns depends on the data, I can't predefine the columns.

I look only for a possibility to display that data as table.
The **database**-table is like

```
The pk of the row (to identify which student)
The year for which this is the average
The value, in this example the average
```

Comment: I would assume OP means "make dynamic"

Answer (score 0):

**I misread the question; this doesn't answer it.**

As I understand it, you want a value for each row for each year? Let's say each row is a student, and you want the average grade for each year for each student.

Not really an answer to the question, but an alternative (easier?) way to do this is to have a table with three columns:

1. The `pk` of the row (to identify which student)
2. The `year` for which this is the average
3. The `value`, in this example the average

Here `pk` and `year` are unique together (a student can have only one averge per year).

Do you want the database to enforce that each student has an average for each year, or can there be empty years (NULL values in your database setup)?

I don't know much about your situation, but in many cases I think this is the simpler solution, as it does not require the structure of your database to change each year, just the data in it.

Comment: Thanks for answer. My database model is like You describe. I ask now for a possibility for representation. I extend now my question.

Comment: Understood it wrongly sorry. I don't know if what you ask is possible.